# Refactoring code for drawing game components

Tags: c++, architecture, refactoring

How can I refractor the following, to move my drawing functions from the h-file into a GraphicsManager class?

```
//drawingFunctions.h
void drawTexturedQuad( Texture texture, Vector2 pos, Vector2 dim) {
    // bind texture...
    glBegin(...);    // draw  
    //...
    glEnd(...);
}

//class file
#include "drawingFunctions.h"
class Player { 
    void drawPlayer(){ drawTexturedQuad( texture, pos, dim) } 
};
class Enemy { 
    void drawEnemy(){ drawTexturedQuad( texture, pos, dim) } 
};
class Item { 
    void drawItem(){ drawTexturedQuad( texture, pos, dim) } 
};
// and so on for the other components

//gameloop file
// instantiate components objects
while (true) {
    // input, logic
    Player.drawPlayer();
    Enemy.drawEnemy();
    Item.drawItem();
    // and so on
}
```

(The code is obviously simplified, I am just asking about the drawing here)

Should I...

- pass a pointer to the GraphicsManager to every call of drawPlayer, drawEnemy etc from within the gameloop
- have Player, Enemy etc have a pointer to GraphicsManger as a data member
- have Player, Enemy etc extend a drawableGameComponent class that has a pointer to GraphicsManager as a data member
- something else?

Comment: There have been several discussions around this topic on http://gamedev.stackexchange.com Perhaps worth a look.

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like a perfect use case for inheritance:

```
class Drawable
{
public:
    void draw()
    {
         // gl stuff
    }

protected:
     Texture _texture;
     Vector2 _pos;
     Vector2 _dim;
};


class Player : Drawable
{
public:
     // should modify _texture _pos and _dim somewhere.       
};

// same thing for the other objects.
```

Comment: What if you wanted to use *cough* Direct X, or SDL, or a test renderer to nail down regressions?

Comment: @PeterWood : well I guess that's not the question. I didn't mention any constructor in `Drawable`, if you need to do some initialization, there's nothing to prevent you from adding it.

Comment: @PeterWood Well, in `draw()` it would probably be better to call the appropriate method of the renderer, rather than sticking the OpenGL code in directly.

Answer (score 1):

I would pass a renderer to the model, and ask it to draw itself.

```
class Player
{
public:
    void draw(Renderer& renderer);
};

class Enemy
{
public:
    void draw(Renderer& renderer);
};
```

Note you don't have to name the function `drawPlayer` or `drawEnemy`, because you already know that it's a `Player` or an `Enemy` by the class type. This uniform calling convention is perfect for extracting into a common interface:

```
class Model
{
public:
    virtual void draw(Renderer& renderer) = 0;

    virtual ~Model() {}
};
```

Then you can have each of your models inherit from `Model`, and each implement `draw`.

As I mentioned in a comment on @J.N.'s answer you can also have Renderer be an abstract class. For example I worked on a project which used OpenGL, GDI+, and also needed to create printouts of schematics.

```
class Renderer
{
public:
    virtual render(const Triangle& triangle, const Texture& texture) = 0;

    virtual ~Renderer() {}
};
```

Comment: Just to make sure I understand it correctly, your `draw(renderer)` would then call `render(...)`, right? Apart from that: Why would I prefer passing the reference to renderer on each call to `draw(...)` over just having it as a data member in the Model and passing it into the constructor of the components derived from Model?

Comment: Well, you can change it at runtime I guess. I meant that `Renderer` would have many functions for renderering various objects like text, triangles, circles, bitmaps, etc. So each model would use renderer differently. But looking at your example again, which I perhaps wrongly assumed was simplified, you are calling `drawTexturedQuad` exactly the same way for each one. So there isn't a variation in the drawing code as mine allows, and perhaps @J.N's answer is all you need.

Comment: There might well be a variation lateron. So why the reference to renderer instead of passing a pointer to the component's constructor? I still don't see the reason?

Comment: @Ben Maybe the model is created before the renderer, maybe the renderer will change. Maybe you want to render the same model in different windows. It also makes the models smaller. I prefer references because they're never invalid, so don't need checking.

Answer (score 0):

I would go for the first possibility: **passing the pointer to the GraphicsManager in the call**.  Eventhough it seems a bit overkill, the knowledge of which GraphicsManager is used is maintained on higher level and can be modified easier later on.

Having said this, I would still inherit from a Drawable interface and put the items that need to be drawn in a container, so you can just iterate through it to display the items via a virtual drawItem() function.
Like so (C++03, not tested):

```
std::vector<Drawable*> Items;
Items.push_back(&player);
Items.push_back(&enemy);
...
for (std::vector<Drawable*>::iterator it = Items.begin(); it != Items.end(): ++it)
{
  (*it)->drawItem(&graphMgr);
}
```

Comment: Could you explain the second part of your answer in more detail, please? What I understand is the `virtual` part where I give the (abstract) `Drawable` class a `virtual` member function `drawItem()`. What I don't understand is the part about the container, or at least how these two are related?

Comment: Thx for the edit. I think that's a separate issue. At the moment, I am actually using manager-classes (EnemyManager, ItemManager) to maintain lists of components and then iterate through the list element's draw methods when it comes to rendering.

Comment: @Ben: That's why I wrote "Having said this".  It addressed the sequential calling of different non-virtual functions in your example.  With the example code, it now dominates the real answer.